# New to Python and Pandas, Looking for help aggregating observations

Tags: pandas

I am relatively new to using Python and Pandas, and was looking for help with this line of code:

```
`Football.ydstogo[Football.ydstogo>='11']&[Football.ydstogo<='19']= '10-plus`'
```

I am working with data from the NFL, and trying to build a model to predict when a team will pass, or when a team will run the ball. One of my variables (ydstogo) measures the distance for the team, with the ball, to get a first down. I am trying to group together the observations after 10 yards for ease of visualization.

When I tried running the code above, the error in my output is "can't assign to operator". I've used this code before to change gender observations to dummy variables, so I'm confused why it is not working here.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to find elements with (string)
value between *'11'* and *'19'* and set a new string there.

So probably your should change your code to:

```
Football.ydstogo[(Football.ydstogo >= '11') & (Football.ydstogo <= '19')] = '10-plus'
```

Alternative:

```
Football.ydstogo[Football.ydstogo.between('11', '19')] = '10-plus'
```